# Nginx reverse proxy configuration makes Mojolicious $self->req->url->to_abs discard the port number

Tags: perl, vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, mojolicious

Stuck on in the implementation of a "quick and dirty" web resource link sharing functionality, which should work according to the following scenario:

- user lists items from db, clicks on edit
- system opens edit modal dialog with selected app
- the system presents the link to **this** item in **this** application instance, so that with couple of tabs the user can Ctrl + C or Cmd + C it ...

So I have the following code in the mojolicious template, which Mojolicious perfectly translates into the correct absolute url, while running without nginx reverse proxy:

```
 <input id="modal-dia-share-lnk" @focus="this.document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)"
 :value="'<%=  $self->req->url->to_abs =%>?&'+'with=id-eq-'+this.$attrs.id.replace('dia-','')" readonly>
```

which translates to something like:

`http://host-name:8082/qto/list/monthly_issues_202004?&with=id-eq-200327122837`
which **HAS** the port

but, while running behind reverse proxy it omits the port, so even if I am running on port 441
the generated url is does **NOT** have the port
`http://qto.fi/qto/list/monthly_issues_202004?&with=id-eq-200325163720`

Which is kind of unacceptable in this [setup](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/master/doc/md/installations_doc.md#22-target-setup), because the Mojo app layer for **dev** must be listening to port **441** and the Mojo app layer for **prd** must be listening to port **443**

You can actually get the scenario in both the:

- the qto app layer instance in [dev](https://qto.fi:441/qto/logon)
- the qto app layer instance in [prd](https://qto.fi:443/qto/logon)

by just clicking ok to be logged on with the default anonymous user ...

I could build the url based on the existing configuration of the app, but I guess there should be quick nginx hack to actually include the port as well by some regex in the location directive or something ...

This is the reverse proxy [conf](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/master/cnf/nginx/etc/nginx/sites-available/%25env%25.https-site.conf):

```
server {

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name qto.fi;
  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qto.fi/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qto.fi/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 10s;
  }
}
```

there is also the following http conf for the dev site:

```
server {
    listen 78;
    listen [::]:78;

    server_name qto.fi;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8078/;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For
         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         # ....

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the port to the Host header in the nginx reverse proxy conf:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:443;
```

OR

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

Answer (score 1):

A kind of workaround, based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61618052/65706) of [ttubrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187389/ttubrian), 
but STILL not exactly the real solution might be

to build the url by `proxy_set_header Host $host:78;`

so the https conf would look as follows:

```
server {

  listen 441 ssl;
  server_name qto.fi;
  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qto.fi/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qto.fi/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8078/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:78;
    proxy_read_timeout 10s;
  }
}
```

which generates the following type of url:

`http://qto.fi:78/qto/list/problems?&with=id-eq-200325184202`

and adding the http -> https enforcement in the http dev conf:

`return 301 https://$host:441$request_uri;`

so the dev conf would look as follows:

```
 server {
    listen 78;
    listen [::]:78;

    server_name qto.fi;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    return 301 https://$host:441$request_uri;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8078/;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For
         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: So... you included the port number in the Host header. Sounds a lot like the answer given.

Comment: yes but the actual scheme aka "https" was not there .... hence the work around ...